# Gson with Hibernate - Error when trying to load a Lazy attribute

Tags: java, json, hibernate, gson

I have a class implemented as follows:

```
public class User implements Serializable  {

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "USER_LOG")
private String log;

@Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD")
private String password;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "CATG_USER_FK",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CATG_TOUSERFK_FK")
)
private List<Category> categories;
```

As you can see, List categories is Lazy loaded by Hibernate when needed.

In other piece of code, I want to obtain a JSON string from an object User correctly loaded by Hibernate:

```
    User oneUser = BBDDController.getUserById(1L);
    System.out.println("User is: " + oneUser.getLog());//just to check.
    //Now its time to transform to JSON.
    Gson son = new Gson();
    String str= son.toJson(oneUser);
    System.out.println("String of JSON: " + str);
```

And then it comes the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:445)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:270)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:566)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:310)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.write(TypeAdapters.java:295)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:976)
```

This error is repeated again and again.
If I try with a fake User loading with a List loaded by code (I meant, if I create the User object by code with no Hibernate intervention), Gson works fine.

Some help, please? Loading from Hibernate is fine, but it seems that Lazy doesnt work with Gson. Hibernate session is always opened. I want to avoid fetch = FetchType.EAGER in User, and if I try with this option it crashes on the same way anyway.

Thank you.

----- EDIT ------
Maybe Hibernate has nothing wrong here. I tryied by creating a large List of categories for User, and the error is the same. Maybe is there any restriction with number of elements of a list or type of this elements in Gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Category have reference to User ? If yes it pretty obvious

gson using reflecion its going to category and from category back to the same user

to ignore propty during serialization u can use

```
@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
```

Comment: Category doesn't reference to User, but It's true that Caregory can reference other categories.
So, how can I configure Gson to avoid recurrences?
Thank you, Bartun.

Comment: Anyway, I read somewhere that Gson its a bad idea for this purpose, and maybe its a Jackson a better choice. Are you agree with that?

Comment: Jackson is for sure more popular I would go with Jackson u could probably find some comparison online

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ;)

Comment: This is the way. Thank you.